# What is "legal authority" which is required for iOS developer program?

Tags: ios, developer-program

I am trying to enroll into iOS Developer Program as government organization.

One of the requirements is:

> The legal authority to bind your company/organization to Apple Developer Program legal agreements.

I am having some confusions with understanding that.

Is it just requiring an ID for a responsible person on the organization, let say the IT manager?

Comment: someone with authority to sign a legal document 'for & on behalf' of the company. Only your company/organisation can know who that would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's phrasing is deliberately wide because the terms need to cover a wide range of countries and legal systems.

Depending on the jurisdiction you are in, the meaning of [legal authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_authority) will differ. Typically, it means the individual agreeing has the power to make a binding agreement between the individual or organisation and Apple Inc.

As an example, a **Limited Liability** company registered in [England and Wales](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/companies-house) would typically require a **Director** to make the agreement. The Director in this case being able to represent the company unlike an employee or sub-contractor.

As always, if you are unsure of your legal role or position, please get professional advice.